# A function with a std::function parameter does not accept a lamba function

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, lambda, std-function

I am trying to get more familiar with the C++11 standard by implementing the `std::iterator` on my own doubly linked list collection and also trying to make my own `sort` function to sort it.

I would like the `sort` function to accept a lamba as a way of sorting by making the `sort` accept a `std::function`, but it does not compile (I do not know how to implement the `move_iterator`, hence returning a copy of the collection instead of modifying the passed one).

```
template <typename _Ty, typename _By>
LinkedList<_Ty> sort(const LinkedList<_Ty>& source, std::function<bool(_By, _By)> pred)
{
    LinkedList<_Ty> tmp;
    while (tmp.size() != source.size())
    {
        _Ty suitable;
        for (auto& i : source) {
            if (pred(suitable, i) == true) {
                suitable = i;
            }
        }
        tmp.push_back(suitable);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Is my definition of the function wrong? If I try to call the function, I recieve a compilation error.

```
LinkedList<std::string> strings{
    "one",
    "two",
    "long string",
    "the longest of them all"
};

auto sortedByLength = sort(strings, [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b){
    return a.length() < b.length();
});
```

> **Error:** no instance of function template "sort" matches the argument
>   list argument types are: (LinkedList, lambda []bool
>   (const std::string &a, const std::string &)->bool)

Additional info, the compilation also gives the following error:

> **Error** 1   error C2784: 'LinkedList<_Ty> sort(const
>   LinkedList<_Ty> &,std::function)' : could not
>   deduce template argument for '`std::function<bool(_By,_By)>`'

---

**Update:** I know the sorting algorithm is incorrect and would not do what is wanted, I have no intention in leaving it as is and do not have a problem fixing that, once the declaration is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `_By` used inside `std::function` like this cannot be deduced from a lambda closure. You'd need to pass in an actual `std::function` object, and not a lambda. Remember that the type of a lambda expression is an unnamed class type (called the closure type), and *not* `std::function`.

What you're doing is a bit like this:

```
template <class T>
void foo(std::unique_ptr<T> p);

foo(nullptr);
```

Here, too, there's no way to deduce `T` from the argument.

How the standard library normally solves this: it does not restrict itself to `std::function` in any way, and simply makes the type of the predicate its template parameter:

```
template <typename _Ty, typename _Pred>
LinkedList<_Ty> sort(const LinkedList<_Ty>& source, _Pred pred)
```

This way, the closure type will be deduced and all is well.

Notice that you don't *need* `std::function` at all—that's pretty much only needed if you need to *store* a functor, or pass it through a runtime interface (not a compiletime one like templates).

---

Side note: your code is using identifiers which are reserved for the compiler and standard library (identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter). This is not legal in C++, you should avoid such reserved identifiers in your code.

Comment: Thank you Angew, that did work. I am perfectly fine with C++ until you introduce templates, which basically means I cannot program in C++ at all. Thanks for the side note as well, coming from a PHP world we do not really have anything like that. Much appreciated.

Comment: By the way, there is only a problem with the naming convention, am I correct? There is no way that just because I name my template parameters the way I did, they would interfere with the standard library. Or is there some special quirk to templating which may break it all?

Comment: @DavidPacker It could be a real problem. That's because the standard library is allowed to use such names for any purpose, including macros. Imagine how your code would cope with something like `#define _By (void)` somewhere in the standard library headers...

Comment: @Angew a side question about the lambda and std::function. Making the function type a template parameter is indeed the practice in the standard library, but I thought a lambda was convertible to a std:: function object with a matching signature. Am I wrong, or is the original problem with OP's lambda related to the mismatched signature of the std::function arguments with _By=string vs. the lambda signature with const string&?

Comment: @JavierMartín A lambda is indeed convertible to a `std::function` with a compatible (not necessarily identical) signature. The OP's problem is that the `_By` inside `std::function<>` cannot be deduced from the lambda, just as the `T` cannot be deduced from `nullptr` in my `foo` example.

Comment: Oh, the preprocessor definition makes sense, Angew. Thank you for the clalirification. I thought the template typenames were limited by scope and/or would override global specifiers. Anyway, once again thank you for the solution. I noticed it in the STL, the similar approach, but it just seemed weird.

Comment: @DavidPacker The standard library not only *can* use such names, it pretty much *has to.* Otherwise, it would be susceptible to the opposite problem: user-defined macros messing up its own internals.

Comment: Seems reasonable. :-)